# What is the plastic material of the CD cases?

Tags: materials, plastics

What is the material of which the transparent part of CD cases are made of? It is nicely rigid and really lightweight.

[image: cd case]

Answer (score 4):

These are called slimline jewel cases.

From the Wikipedia article on [Optical Disc Packaging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_disc_packaging#Slimline_jewel_case):

> The bulk of slimline cases are made with translucent or transparent **polystyrene**, and are available in multiple colors. A stronger alternative is made from semi-opaque, semi-flexible **polypropylene** which is strong enough to protect the disc, but flexible enough not to break easily.

[Here is an image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polystyrene#mediaviewer/File:Caja_de_CD.jpg) of a polystyrene case to compare to yours:
[image]

Comment: The back part of the case in this picture is HIPS, PS-PB copolymer, as the description on wikipedia says, the transparent front cover plain PS. The case in the OPs picture is likely all standard PS.

Answer (score 3):

CD jewel cases are made from injection molded polystyrene.  Clam-shell alternatives use polypropylene.